# Two sets A and B are dense in a metric space X. Is the intersection (A ∩ B) also dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

edit: sorry I was a bit unclear in the last post

For this is take 3 cases:

1. A and B both being open. (Intersection is dense)
2. One of A and B being open (Intersection is dense)
3. Neither of A and B being open (Intersection is not dense - i think..?)

For both A and B being open and dense, A ∩ B will also be dense in X.

Proof: Let x ∈ X, and let U be a neighborhood of x. Since A is dense, x lies in the closure
of A, so U intersects A at a point y. Note that U ∩ A is a neighborhood of y, being the
intersection of two open sets. Since B is dense, y lies in the closure of B, so U∩A intersects B
at a point z. Then z ∈ U ∩ A ∩ B, which proves that U intersects A ∩ B, and therefore x
lies in the closure of A ∩ B.

I got this proof online, but is there an easier/simpler explanation?

For neither A and B being open A ∩ B is not dense. I don't know how to prove that. Really appreciate the help!

Thanks!

Comment: Rationals and irrationals.

Comment: But this is not true, right? For example, $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb  R \backslash \mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, but their intersection is empty.

Comment: Use this: a  set is dense iff its complement has no open subsets.

Answer (score 5):

No. The rationals and irrationals are dense in the real numbers. Their intersection is the nullset, is not dense.

Comment: Thanks. But what does this prove? The rationals/irrartionals are neither open nor closed. Doesn't that refute the statement that the intersection of two open dense sets is not dense?

Comment: No it doesn't refute that.

Comment: What this shows is that the answer to the question in your title is "no". It also shows any attempt at proving an answer of "yes" fails in case 3.

Answer (score 1):

The third case does not provide enough information to determine whether $A\cap B$ is dense or not.  An example of $A\cap B$ being empty shows that it *may not* be dense.

To give an example of $A\cap B$ being dense, despite neither $A$ nor $B$ being open, consider the subset of real numbers $C = \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, and let $A = C^c = \mathbb{R} \setminus C$ and $B = -A = \{-x : x\in A \}$.

Then neither $A$ nor $B$ is open since $C$ is not closed, but $A\cap B$ is dense since it includes all irrational numbers.

Shout out to @drhab, who pointed out in a Comment on the Question (now removed) that we can simply take $B = A$ with $A$ dense but not open (e.g. as constructed above).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you define "dense". I guess you are using the most natural definition: a set is dense if it meets every nonempty open set.

Case 2. If $A$ and $B$ are dense sets and $A$ is open, then $A\cap B$ is dense.

Proof. Let $U$ be a nonempty open set. Since $A$ is dense, $U\cap A\ne\emptyset.$ Since $U$ and $A$ are open sets, $U\cap A$ is open. Since $U\cap A$ is a nonempty open set, and since $B$ is dense, $A\cap B$ is dense.

Case 3. If $A$ and $B$ are dense sets, $A\cap B$ is not necessarily dense; e.g., in the space of real numbers, consider $A$ the set of rational numbers and $B$ the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: E is dense in X if the closure of E = X.

Comment: Does that change anything?

Comment: @mathinthecity Yes, "the closure of $E$ is $X$" is a valid *characterization* of dense sets. Not as clear and intuitive as the *definition* I gave, but it has its uses.

Comment: Does *what* change anything?

Comment: @bof some books have that as the definition;

Comment: @Alephnull Some people like complicated definitions and complicated proofs. I'm not as smart as those people, so I like to keep things simple. As you can imagine, I never got very far in mathematics.